# How to change the execute time of job in hangfire which is currently scheduled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I have a job which is scheduled for a specific time. Based on some condition I want to change the execution time of that job. Currently I have following logic which delete previously scheduled job and schedule new one.

```
BackgroundJob.Delete("1033");
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
           () => InvokeMethod(objInvokerDetail),
            time);
```

Is it possible to change the execute time of currently scheduled job without deleting it and scheduling new one?

Comment: You can schedule a new job with similar (not the same) name.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so it is impossible to change the execute time of job without creating new job

Answer (score 0):

According to this (albeit old) [Forum Post](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/change-time-span-of-an-existing-job/208) it is not possible to change an existing job.

What is recommended you do is keep the id of the job you scheduled and delete the job (before it fires) and Schedule a new one with your new time.

```
string jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("A job"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);
string rescheduleJobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Same New Job!"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```